# Some servers do not accept mail from my server: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Tags: postfix, exim

I have the following problem. I use Gmail mail services for my domain name **mydomain.com**. My server with hostname **server.my-datacenter.net** sends messages to the users of my website with "from" and "reply-to" address **info@mydomain.com**. Postfix (and Exim on my second server) automatically adds email addresses **root@server.my-datacenter.net** or **www-data@server.my-datacenter.net** to all outgoing emails.

Some mail servers are not accepting emails from my server because **server.my-datacenter.net** itself does not accept mail. I can not create MX records for **server.my-datacenter.net** to make my server accept external emails because this domain/subdomain belongs to my data center and was assigned automatically as a hostname. I can not change hostname from **server.my-datacenter.net** to **mydomain.com** because in this case I can not have PTR record (my datacenter wants 5 EUR/month for a custom PTR record).

Server's IP address has a reverse PTR record to **server.my-datacenter.net**. Domain name **mydomain.com** has a SPF record (included Gmail + my server's IP address).

What can I do in this situation? Is it possible to force Exim and Postfix to use **root@mydomain.com** and **www-data@mydomain.com** instead of **root@server.my-datacenter.net** and **www-data@server.my-datacenter.net**? If yes, how can I do it in Postfix and Ensim.

If I do it, is it OK that outgoing email will contain email addresses with a different domain (not a server's hostname)?

```
2DBF7646459     1219 Wed Feb 20 11:46:01  root@server.my-datacenter.net
(host a.mail.server[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] said: 450 4.1.8 <root@server.my-datacenter.net>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
                                         email@address
```

Comment: The 0 in the domain is due to a copy error or a configuration error ?I can't resolve server.my-datacenter.net nor server.my0datacenter.net, but it is maybe normal...

Comment: It's an error. I replaced the real domain names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't explicitly set the hostname to use, exim when it starts up makes a valiant effort to figure it out from the hostname of the machine and/or the IP address.  To override this in exim, explicitly set what you want it to be.  Add to the global section of your config:

```
primary_hostname = mail.mydomain.com
```

...which assumes that hostname mail.mydomain.com resolves to the IP address of your mail server.  Now when it receives email from non-qualified users, it will append @mail.mydomain.com instead of @server.my-datacenter.net.

Comment: Thanks Todd. Do you know what I need to change in Postfix? /etc/postfix/main.cf file contains: myhostname = server.my-datacenter.net, mydestination = server.my-datacenter.net, localhost.my-datacenter.net, , localhost, myorigin = /etc/mailname which contains server.my-datacenter.net. What is the difference among "myhostname", "mydestination" and "myorigin"?